# Strange results for Dataframe.duplicated() | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to find duplicates in a column in dataframe of dtype
`string[python]`
When I run
`x['comment'].duplicated()`, I get the following output

```
1         False
2         False
3         False
4         False
          ...  
155071     True
155072     True
155073     True
155074     True
155075     True
```

I then decide to see what the contents of the strings are using `x['comment'].iloc[155071:155075]`. This gives me the following output

```
155071    Hola. @strange67 en mí debut, coincidió que se...
155072    Yo estuve altísima un tiempo ( la glico de 16 ...
155073    Hola strange67,yo cuando debute hace 32 anos s...
155074    No soy medico ni nada pero partiendo de eso, h...
Name: comment, dtype: string
```

As you can see the string are not at all duplicates. So I rerun the duplicated function only for these few rows; `x['comment'].iloc[155071:155075].duplicated()`. It now says that the contents are not duplicate

```
155071    False
155072    False
155073    False
155074    False
Name: comment, dtype: bool
```

Am I doing something wrong or interpreting the way duplicated() works in the wrong way? How do I find duplicate records? Because `drop_duplicates()` function removes a major chunk of my non-duplicate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, [pandas.Series.Duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas-series-duplicated) looks for duplicates anywhere in the column. You used the default `keep="first"` parameter, so the first occurrence is not flagged. Each of these strings are duplicated somewhere above.

The same thing is happening in this simplified example

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})
>>> df['a'].duplicated()
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
dtype: bool
```

You could do `x['comment'] == 'Hola. @strange67 en mí debut, coincidió que se...` to find all of the matches for a single value. Or `x['comment'].duplicated(keep=False)` to mark all of them.